# iPhone:Weird blank white screen at startup after migrating my app to IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have a weird problem, dont know which code should I post because I dont know where is the problem, but please ask for more code sample if you need;

My app was build with "Xcode 3.2 and IOS 4.3" Then recently I started to use Xcode 4.2 with base IOS 5; Opened my project with new environment **and set deployment target to IOS 4.3.** App works same and well but I have one problem;

App starts with splash screen well and then I supposed to see the first view from the navigation controller but instead I see a blank white screen! and it stays still..then here is the surprize; when I press home button and then open app again from suspended mode then I can get the first view correctly! Which parts of my code should I check? Or is it a configuration problem I can fix from build settings? When I debug I can hit the "viewDidAppear" method of the viewController but actually all I see is a white screen.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here, in your root (first started) viewcontroller, move any code that displays something, away from the method viewDidLoad into viewDidApear - just to see if it solves your issue

Comment: @Alon Amir Tnx but it did not work.

Comment: After resuming the app, you said it shows your view fine. Are you doing any display actions on applicationDidBecomeActive?

Comment: @Alon Amir  I dont use that method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You often see this if you are creating your main UIWindow in code but there is an extra UIWindow defined in your nib file. In iOS 4 the window you create in code appears above the nib-defined window. In iOS 5 it is the other way round - the empty nib-defined window appears above your window created in code.

If you *are* creating your main window in code then check your nib file, remove any extra window and remove the Main Nib File setting from your info.plist file.

Comment: thanks I will check what you say, my app is a navigation based application which I created it as a window based and then later made it navigation based manually. But then why it works well when I suspend it back?

Comment: Who knows - iOS is designed to have one main UIWindow. If you have two then all bets are off. Given your starting point I'm almost certain you will find that there is an extra window in your nib. Remove it and the problem will go away.

Comment: THANKS, worked! But When I also remove the Main Nib File setting from info.plist file I get a black window and it does not work.? Also transition from splash screen to View is a bit weird..any optimization can I make here?

Comment: It depends exactly what you are doing and I can't tell that from here. If you are relying on the nib to create your top-level view controller then you still need the Main Nib File setting. Maybe it would be best to create your UIWindow, root view controller *and* splash screen programmatically so that you can be certain they are created exactly when you are expecting and in the order you expect. 'is a bit weird' doesn't tell me much.